# SwiftUI Pass Value from Geometry Reader to Function

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view which uses Geometry Reader to calculate how large the image area should be:

```
GeometryReader { metrics in
    ZStack{
        self.image
           .resizable()
           .frame(width:  (metrics.size.height - 10) * 0.561403509 , height: metrics.size.height - 10, alignment: .top)
           .clipped()
    }
}
```

But I have a function where I want to use the frame height and width calculated by the GeometryReader in order to crop the image.

I have a separate function which crops the image when a button is pressed:

```
 DownloadImageButton(prepareImagefunction: { self.prepareImage() })
```

Which then calls a prepareImage function:

```
func prepareImage( ) {
 // In order for image cropping to work, we need the equivalent of view.bounds in order to adjust the crop so that it correctly measures the crop area. We need metrics.width and metrics.height 
 var adjustmentScaleForDisplaySize = targetSize.width / metrics.width
```

Note that the GeometryReader is a child of the parent view where prepareImage is called. Therefore, ideally, the child would save the metrics values in an EnvironmentObject or Binding to the parent.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you're trying to accomplish, even if it doesn't work? `metric` can be passed into a function just like any other variable, but it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have edited the answer. When the image is presented on screen I need to save the metrics.size in order to later use it in an image cropping function in the parent view. If you think about image cropping, usually you use view.bounds to determine crop area. It's the equivalent requirement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass the value calculated by GeometryReader to a function?

Yes, you can do this. The var `metrics` is a `GeometryProxy`, so function signature should be like in the following example

```
private func resizedImage(for metrics: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
    self.image
       .resizable()
       .frame(width:  (metrics.size.height - 10) * 0.561403509 , height: metrics.size.height - 10, alignment: .top)
       .clipped()
}
```

so your usage

```
GeometryReader { metrics in
    ZStack{
       self.resizedImage(for: metrics)
    }
}
```

**Update: for *changed request***

Assuming you have in child view binding as

```
@Binding var cropSize: CGSize
```

the above function can be modified as follow

```
private func resizedImage(for metrics: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
    let size = CGSize(width: (metrics.size.height - 10) * 0.561403509, 
                           height: metrics.size.height - 10)
    self.cropSize = size
    return self.image
       .resizable()
       .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height, alignment: .top)
       .clipped()
}
```

Comment: This is really great. But what I want to do is pass the value of metrics to an image cropping function. And so I need to capture the metrics height, for example, so that it can be used in a cropping function. I'll append my question but your answer is definitely close to what I'm asking!

Comment: I've now tested and self.cropSize = size throws an error:

[SwiftUI] Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.

The crop size does not get passed along to the parent.

Comment: @dot3, it depends on usage order of `cropSize` and `body` construction (which are not shown), anyway it is not critical situation and usual known solution for it is to make it asynchronous, like: `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.cropSize = size }`

Answer (score 4):

Since I actually ONLY needed the crop size, and didn't necessarily need an image returned, I did the following which also helped to avoid throwing an error which can occur in the accepted answer:

```
[SwiftUI] Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.
```

I added an .onAppear function call which helps to avoid the above error, and then properly passes the crop dimension to the parent:

```
GeometryReader { metrics in
  ZStack{
   self.image
   .resizable()
   .frame(width:  (metrics.size.height - 10) * 0.561403509 , height: metrics.size.height - 10, alignment: .top)
   .clipped()
  }.onAppear{
    self.saveCropSize(for: metrics)
  }....

private func saveCropSize(for metrics: GeometryProxy){
    let size = CGSize(width: (metrics.size.height - 10) * 0.561403509, 
                           height: metrics.size.height - 10)
    self.cropSize = size
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a solution I think is useful, using a new type:

```
public struct GeometryPasser: View {
    private let op: (GeometryProxy) -> Void
    public init(_ op: @escaping (GeometryProxy) -> Void) {
        self.op = op
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear.onAppear {
                op(proxy)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    public func passGeometry(_ op: @escaping (GeometryProxy) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.background(
            GeometryPasser(op)
        )
    }
}
```

and call like:

```
Rectangle()
    .fill(.yellow)
    .passGeometry { geo in
        print("do whatever you want here: \(geo)")
    }
```